# Function to create two command buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I want to simultaneously create two command buttons inside a worksheet.

The function creates only one (the first one).

I segregated the functions, but it still does not add the second button.

```vb
Sub AddCommandButtons()

    Dim sh1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim btn1, btn2 As Shape

    set sh1= ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
      
    x1 = 4.2
    y1 = 1.8
    w1 = 140
    h1 = 21
    
    x2 = 160
    y2 = 1.8
    w2 = 140
    h2 = 21
    
    Set btn1 = sh1.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlButtonControl, x1, y1, w1, h1)
    btn1.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "Add New Lines"
    btn1.OnAction = "Module8.AddNewLines"

    Set btn2 = sh1.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlButtonControl, x2, y2, w2, h2)
    btn2.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "Write Out Lines"
    btn2.OnAction = "Module11.WriteOutLines"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: No repro, works for me.

Comment: On Excel 2010 the code works normally.

Comment: Thanks BigBen and Zer0Kelvin for testing the code out. Interestingly enough, I realized that this issue is merely related to the POSITION of the buttons, i.e. first row which is already expanded in height to accommodate the button. If I keep the default height before adding the buttons, the code works fine. Now, I have another issue: the buttons' width keep growing as I increase the row height. They are "Form Control" with no Properties tab. Is there a way to lock the size through the code?

Comment: In fact, there is the "Don't move or size with cells" option box in the button Properties tab but I do not know how to access this through my code.